# Creating objects and calling their methods based on keywords in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing an interpreter in Python for a very simple language grammar. I have a superclass called `Statement` which has several child classes. I have a method in the superclass called `CreateStatement` that evaluates keywords, and based on the keyword found it creates an instance of a child class object. Some of the child classes will need to call this method.

My problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Statement' object has no attribute 'Assignment'
```

Help!

```
import re
from TokenHandler import TokenHandler
from ParserException import ParserException

class Statement(object):

    tokens = []
    executedTokens = []

    def __init__(self, tokenlist):
        self.tokens = tokenlist

    def getCurrentToken(self):
        print self.tokens[0]
        return self.tokens[0]

    def createStatement(self):
        currenttoken = self.getCurrentToken()

        t = TokenHandler()

        if currenttoken == "print":
            p = Print(self.tokens)
            return p

        elif t.isVariable(currenttoken):
            a = Assignment(self.tokens)
            return a

        elif currenttoken == "if":
            i = IF(self.tokens)
            return i

        elif currenttoken == "while":
            w = While(self.tokens)
            return w

        elif currenttoken == "begin":
            s = self.CompoundStatement(self.tokens)
            return s

        else:
            raise ParserException('Reserved word \'end\' expected')

    #...other methods...
```

---

```
from Statement import Statement
from TokenHandler import TokenHandler
import VariableException

class Assignment(Statement):

    def __init__(self, tokens = []):
        super(Assignment, self).__init__(tokens)

    #...other methods...
```

Comment: so you were expecting that you have defined an attribute called Assignment that exists inside `Statement` but you haven't shown how the class `Statement` is defined, including what methods and data fields it has inside it.

Comment: you may want to look at PLY, which is made for this kind of thing
(http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)

Comment: In the future, please include more code. The error takes place on a line which attempts to reference an attribute of `Statement` but you don't provide a list of the attributes of `Statement` (or its full definition). You also don't show us what this `Assignment` is you're trying to reference.

Comment: Sorry, I went ahead and added more code. Let me know if you need to see more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    a = self.Assignment(self.tokens)
```

is wrong if `Assignment` is a subclass defined at the module level and not an attribute of the `Statement` class or the `self` instance. Did you mean

```
    a = Assignment(self.tokens)
```

This line is probably similarly wrong:

```
    s = self.CompoundStatement(self.tokens)
```

Comment: Yes, `Assignment` is a `Statement` instance but if I delete `self` then I get an undefined variable error.

Comment: @deuteros What is `Assignment`? You haven't given us enough code to know for sure what the line _should_ be, just what it _shouldn't_ be.

Comment: @deuteros `self` is a `Statement` instance, do you mean that `Assignment` is a `Statement` subclass? Those aren't the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. `Assignment` is a `Statement` subclass.

Comment: @deuteros Post the rest of your code. If by "undefined variable error" you mean `NameError` then that line is getting executed before you've defined `Assignment`.

Comment: I have a lot of code. Which part do you want to see? The `Assignment` class?

Comment: The `Assignment` class isn't visible to the `Statement` class because it's in a different file and there is no corresponding `import`. Just adding an import probably still won't work because then you'll have a circular inclusion problem. In general, superclasses needing to know something about their subclasses indicates a design flaw. It looks like you intend for `createStatement` to be some kind of factory function that creates new `Statement` objects, and not a method (functionality) of an existing `Statement`, is that it?

Comment: @deuteros Karl is right. (Adding this comment in case you didn't see Karl's)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, that's what `createStatement` is for. There will be several child classes of `Statement` that will need to call that method. And you're right, I tried adding the import but I have the circular inclusion problem you spoke of.

Comment: Honestly I think your whole design is wrong and I don't really know where to start to salvage it without taking some more steps back and understanding the overall problem. :/ But if it's not functionality of an object, then you at least want to make a `classmethod` or `staticmethod` out of it (because when you call it you won't have a reasonable value for `self`), and you honestly should probably just use a top-level function. That lets you solve the problem by putting it somewhere else, although I don't really understand why you have `tokens` as an attribute of `Statement`.

Comment: @deuteros You need to ask a separate question if you need help figuring out how your classes should be organized. The reason for the error (and the error you get if you remove `self`) has been explained. Remember, Python isn't Java -- you don't need to have one class per file. (You also should use lowercase module names, and lower_case_with_underscore method names).

Comment: BTW, you do realize that the `tokens = []; executedTokens = []` lines make those attributes of the *class*, not of individual instances, yeah?

Comment: Okay then, maybe my problem is different and bigger than I had originally understood. Is there a good resource that explains and gives examples of the Python paradigm of class organization?

Comment: @deuteros I'm not sure where I'd look for examples of that, other than any random Python project on github or bitbucket. The simplest method would be for `Statement` and its subclasses to all be in the same file, with a module level function to transform a `Statement` into a subclass. I wouldn't call it "createStatement" since it's not creating a `Statement`. The second simplest would be to organize the classes and subclasses into whatever files you want, then create another module / file that imports all of them and contains the function.

Comment: @agf Okay, thanks for your help. Looks like I have some research to do.